# Testing a soap service with basic auth in qaf

Tags: bdd, qaf

I have sent a soap service for which I have to send basic auth (username and password) along with request and header values in qaf. I tried adding username and password in application.properties file but the service is throwing internal server error. Please guide me how can we do it.

Comment: will you please share your web service request call and exception details as well?

Answer (score 0):

If it is basic authentication you can try providing credential in url, For example: `http://user:pwd@url.com`. Other alternate is register client that takes care of authentication using property `rest.client.impl`. Few of ready to use implementations are available with [qaf-support-ws](https://github.com/qmetry/qaf-support-ws/blob/master/src/com/qmetry/qaf/automation/rest/client) library. You can try `BasicAuthRestClient` as below:

```
rest.client.impl=com.qmetry.qaf.automation.rest.client.BasicAuthRestClient
rest.client.basic.auth.username=username
rest.client.basic.auth.password=password
```

This should work for any webservice call regardless of type rest or soap. Keep in mind that in case of soap, method always be `POST`

Comment: i tried this method but still i am getting 500 internal server error from the server. when i remove username and password details web service throws the invalid username password error , with these details its throwing random fault.  I will try to post the exact error.

Comment: Did you tried by setting `rest.client.impl=com.qmetry.qaf.automation.rest.client.BasicAuthRestClient` and providing credentials as suggested above?

Comment: Yes I tried by providing the same details as you insisted. I have to try providing the credentials in url.

Comment: Share your request call and exception details. Error code 500 usually not because of authontication.

Comment: hi, i tried the basicAuthRestClient params you shared above , added them to application.properties file, but getting below error.  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <env:Header>
   </env:Header>
   <env:Body>
      <env:Fault>
         <faultcode>env:Server
         </faultcode>
         <faultstring>
         </faultstring>
         <detail fault:type="faultDetails" xmlns:fault="http://www.example.com/soapfaults">
         </detail>
      </env:Fault>
   </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>

Comment: below is the request call <call>{
   "baseUrl":"url",
   "method":"POST",
   "headers":{
   "Content-Type":"text/xml",
   "SOAPAction": "soapaction"
   },
   "body":"file:example.xml"
   }
  </call>

Comment: HI, Any comments on this problem?

Comment: This looks server error. Make sure you are providing correct soap  action and sending message body with soap envelope or what expected by server.